# makefile: Build object file if c-file exists

Tags: c, makefile

I have a c-file that is using a compiler flag. When the compiler flag changes, I force the c-file to update it's value by in the makefile writing:

```
compilerflagChange: FORCE
    echo ${CFLAGS} | cmp -s - $@ || echo ${CFLAGS} > $@

myCFile.o: compilerflagChange
```

This works pretty good except when I clean the whole project and then run.
In that case, myCFile.C has not been generated before coming to the statement

```
myCFile.o: compilerflagChange
```

which will cause the build to crash with the error "MyCfile.C, no such file".

Question: How can I make my rule depending on if the C-file exists or not? "If the file exists + cflagChange, update the file, otherwise to nothing"

MORE INFO:
"Why don't you just re-build myCFile.o after that MyCFile.c is generated every time?" No proper place in the makefile. For this, I need to go some layers down and lose tracability of the reason of rebuilding it.

Comment: What's the compiler flag, jw?

Comment: Doesn't matter? variable=readAValueFromCmdInput CFLAGS+=- DVARIABLE="\"${variable}\

Comment: Why would the C file not exist? Is it created by preprocessing? There's something peculiar about this setup — but I can't work out what you're doing (or trying to do). Are you trying to rebuild `myCFile.o` if either the source code for it changes or the compiler options change? But the source code doesn't always exist, but if the object file does exist, it should be treated as up to date and doesn't need recompiling? Maybe the `myCFile.o` rule might need an explicit dependency on `myCFile.c` and the needs to be a rule to ensure `myCFile.c` is created and up to date, but I'm missing something.

Comment: What do you want Make to do if `MyCfile.C` does not exist?

Comment: After cleaning project:
1. myCFile.c is updated with new value if compilerflags has changed (also detect first-time-build as a change)
2. "Build starts" - some object files are generated from c-files
3. "Build ongoing" - Some c-files are generated (including MyCFile.C)
4. "Build ongoing" - more object files are generated from the c-files in step 3.

If I run the build without cleaning, step 3 is not performed. Step 4 is using the already existing files where the value needs to be changed based on the compiler flag.

Comment: If MyCfile.c does not exsists, no nothing. (This step is not working. Or I have no code) Then it will be generated automaticly in later steps and automaticly use the compilerflag.

Comment: If MyCfile.c exists - update the value (This step is working). The generator in later steps (step 4) will notice that the file exists and just use it.

Comment: If `MyCfile.C` is generated by something, you should have a rule for it. E.g., `MyCFile.C: MyCFile.C.in   \n\tpreprocessor < $^ > $@`.

Answer (score 1):

What about make conditionals?

```
ifneq ($(wildcard MyCfile.C),)
myCFile.o: compilerflagChange
endif
```

Note: your use of letter case is really unusual (`myCFile.o` vs. `MyCfile.C`). I know that the most popular operating systems are case insensitive but you should seriously consider a more consistent spelling scheme. Portability, especially when it is free, is a good thing.